# How do I call an Electron API method from the renderer process?

Tags: javascript, jquery, electron

I've been trying http://electron.atom.io for a while. I followed the http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/quick-start/ and with relative success I managed to make an "app" using Bootstrap and Jquery.

But now, I'm trying to use Electron API methods but with no success.

I created a Browser Window, and within that Window I added a new JS file. Within that file, I'm trying to call printToPDF method here: http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/web-contents/#contentsprinttopdfoptions-callback

It just doesn't work and the console logs the following:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: mainWindow is not defined**

The code goes as this:

main.js

```
const electron = require('electron')
const app = electron.app
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow

let mainWindow

function createWindow () {
 mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})
 mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`)
 mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

 mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
  mainWindow = null
 })
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
 if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
  app.quit()
 }
})

app.on('activate', function () {
 if (mainWindow === null) {
  createWindow()
 }
})
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Hello World!</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
</body>

<script>window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
 require('./app.js');
</script>
</html>
```

app.js

```
$(function() {
 mainWindow.webContents.printToPDF();
});
```

Comment: in your served html/js you don't have access to anything in `main.js`. You can make a function in `app.js` that emits an event, then in your `main.js` you can listen for that event and call `mainWindow.webContents.printToPDF();` there when the event gets triggered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the ipc modules, [ipcMain](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/ipc-main/) and [ipcRenderer](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/ipc-renderer/). The ipc module allows you to send and receive synchronous and asynchronous messages between the main and the render process.

Here the print to PDF example from the [**ELECTRON API DEMOS**](http://electron.atom.io/#get-started) app.

**Renderer Process**

```
const ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer

const printPDFBtn = document.getElementById('print-pdf')

printPDFBtn.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  ipc.send('print-to-pdf')
})

ipc.on('wrote-pdf', function (event, path) {
  const message = `Wrote PDF to: ${path}`
  document.getElementById('pdf-path').innerHTML = message
})
```

**Main Process**

```
const fs = require('fs')
const os = require('os')
const path = require('path')
const electron = require('electron')
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow
const ipc = electron.ipcMain
const shell = electron.shell

ipc.on('print-to-pdf', function (event) {
  const pdfPath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'print.pdf')
  const win = BrowserWindow.fromWebContents(event.sender)
  // Use default printing options
  win.webContents.printToPDF({}, function (error, data) {
    if (error) throw error
    fs.writeFile(pdfPath, data, function (error) {
      if (error) {
        throw error
      }
      shell.openExternal('file://' + pdfPath)
      event.sender.send('wrote-pdf', pdfPath)
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I wanted. I'm still trying to figure out this 'module' pattern.